# Phalaenopsis buds drying out

Tags: orchids

[image: The plant]Hi,

My phalaenopsis buds were flowering nicely but are suddenly turning yellow. Can this be because winter is over and the temperatures have risen suddenly. It's also turned very dry. The tropic of cancer passes through the town where I live. Other conditions/watering schedule has not changed and the plant appears otherwise healthy.

Thanks

Comment: Your plant is extremely healthy, note profuse branching flower stalks. Low humidity can cause bud blast.